# MySQL 8 won't autostart at boot on Ubuntu 20.04: Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, systemd, ubuntu-20.04, mysql8

I've a fully up-to-date Ubuntu 20.04 with MySQL 8.0.30 provided by mysql.com.

MySQL is set to autostart at system boot (`systemctl enable mysql`).

Lately I've a problem when I restart the server: MySQL doesn't come up automatically as it used to. The error is:

```
2022-07-31T20:15:09.732753Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
2022-07-31T20:15:09.732836Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2022-07-31T20:15:09.732920Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-07-31T20:15:12.000626Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

From here, if I `sudo ss -lpt` to check the port, I see no process on the `3306` port. Indeed: as soon as I manually `sudo service mysql restart`, the service starts succesfully, no problem whatsoever.

My only relevant MySQL customization is:

```
mysqlx = off
bind-address = 127.0.0.1,172.17.0.1
```

The first address is localhost, while the second one is the Docker interface (this is a physical server, but I've a few containers connecting to it).

What can I do to have MySQL starting at reboot again?

Comment: It seems Docker address gets assigned *later* in the boot sequence than MySQL server is trying to start. You can try to adjust service dependencies (add something "After=docker" into MySQL unit file). But, I'd rather not make it listen on that interface. It is almost saying to you: "don't do that".

Comment: thanks @NikitaKipriyanov ! It looks like that's the issue!